# In logistic regression, why not just use the boundary instead of using probabilities to classify?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

We know that logistic regression assign probabilities that an object belongs to a binary category, say {0,1}. We also know that if the object is "above" or "below" the boundary, it will be 1 or 0 in that category. Why not just use the boundary to classify such objects? What is the point of introducing the sigmoid if the boundary already classifies our objects.

Comment: logistic regression use probability based on the log function to classify.  LR is classifying both the probability and the odds or liklihood of a classification occurring

Comment: How do you decide on the boundary?

Comment: I think that this question is a copy of this one https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32849/why-do-we-need-the-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-regression?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need the sigmoid function in logistic regression?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32849/why-do-we-need-the-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-regression)